# Picture Framing my images in WooCommerce/Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce, frame, photo

I am a photographer and currently attempting to upgrade my site from a Portfolio of my images to a fully functional E-Commerce site.

I have gotten my head around most of the WooCommerce type things I need to do, and I have an idea of what I want. I feel like I can achieve pretty much what I want.

The big problem I'm having is dynamically picture framing my images for sale.

Some examples of what I want:
https://mattlauder.com.au/main-photo-gallery/landscape-gallery/lavender-bay-black-white/#prettyPhoto

https://kenduncan.com/product/docklands-melbourne-vic-vx2101/

Just the ability for me to make a .PNG frame, and have it dynamically added to the background of my images as the variations are selected.

I'm reasonably sure it's a simple coding thing, but I have 0 experience coding.

Any help would be awesome! I couldn't see a simple plugin to do what I want, and I couldn't really see any existing plugin or theme that would add this functionality.

Dan

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that asking general questions like this is discouraged.. questions should only be posted after you have researched your issue and should include  a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and your attempts so far to solve it. Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to edit the images directly, and I don't recommend it because it requires a lot more work.  CSS does the trick!

Since you said you are using woocommerce, I have targeted below the default woocommerce image in the gallery on the single product page.

This is a very basic picture frame - and you can make it a lot cooler if you want it to be (such as a matte)!

```
.woocommerce-product-gallery__image img { 
     border: 15px solid #666;
     padding: 10px;
}
```

Add this code to your theme's custom CSS field.

Comment: Hey Jacob, thanks a lot for the help. Is there a way to display a .PNG object though? I really need to display the actual frame they will be receiving, not just a colour etc.

Comment: Oh! Yes..   Just upload the `.png` as a second image to the product.  Instructions can be found here: https://www.templatemonster.com/help/woocommerce-how-to-add-multiple-product-images-and-manage-product-images-gallery.html

Comment: Sorry mate, totally not what I meant.  I need the PNG to be "layered" or "overlayed" on the custom variant. So say the customer picks an image through a product page, then selects the option to put it in a white frame, I need to dynamically display the image inside the white frame, as the websites I linked above do. The white frame here will be a PNG, and it should be added as an overlay (I think that's the right terminology?) To the specific variant the customer is looking at.   Maybe I'm getting confused by terminology. I tried your suggestion and it literally just adds the frame as a pic

Comment: @Insane I get what you're saying now.  It seems a lot more difficult than it needs to be - since just uploading variants of the product with different frames would provide the same user experience. I will leave my answer up in case it helps someone else out.  good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For something like this https://mattlauder.com.au/main-photo-gallery/landscape-gallery/lavender-bay-black-white/#prettyPhoto

You will need some javascript.

1. Upload the frame png and all frame variations to your WordPress site.
2. Give your image class padding of variable size.
3. In the JavaScript code, replace the background image of your image element. Make sure your background is set to no-repeat.

Some CSS tweaking might be needed to get it to look exactly how you want.